# VBS and Regular Expressions

Tags: windows, regex, file, scripting, vbscript

I am new to RegEx. Can anyone tell me if it's possible to determine if a file name has a specific word in it (like email or games).

And is RegEx the best way to find out? If not what is the best (simplist) way to do this?

Any code samples would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No regex isn't the best way. Use `InStr` like below

```
Dim str, check
str = "filename.txt"
check = "file"
If InStr(1, str, check) > 0 Then
    'Contains
Else
    'Does not contain
End If
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used for finding out if a file name has a specific word in it.

```
Set objRE = New RegExp
objRE.Global     = True
objRE.IgnoreCase = False
objRE.Pattern    = WScript.Arguments(0)

For Each objFile In colFiles
   bMatch = objRE.Test(objFile.Name)
   If bMatch Then
      WScript.Echo objFile.Name
      objFile.Delete
   End If
Next
```